# Is there a decent way to manage accounts across disparate web services?

Tags: user-management, cloud, user-accounts, web-services

I'm in the position of needing to manage the accounts of multiple people across many different types of services, including onboarding and offboarding users. Being that we're using multiple different web-based services which are generally more user focused than company focused, I find myself looking for a tool better than a spreadsheet which will simplify the steps of creating and destroying user accounts and adjusting permissions.

We use GAFYD (google) so in a sense using single sign-on helps, but since most sites offer multiple credentials we really don't have control over accounts created with our user's GAFYD credentials, and permissions in each of the services are still an issue.

I suppose if we can remove all permissions for a certain account to linked data

- Create accounts
- Delete accounts
- Add permissions
- Remove permissions

Answer (score 0):

Well, Lastpass.com might work, I know you can do things like share accounts (so the master shares a specific account for a service with a given user,they log into lastpass, and lastpass logs them in), check out the enterprise version. I've used the personal version for years.